# Function is appending instead of incrementing, having problems

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem where my function is appending instead of adding.

For example I want my result to go from 200 to 201 but instead it's going from 200 to 2001. Any ideas ?

```
btnQuickUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //ref 1
            mAthlete_etCompScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvAttent);
            quickUpdate = String.valueOf(mAthlete_etCompScore.getText().toString());
            quickUpdate = quickUpdate + 1;

Book book = new Book();               
book.setAuthor(quickUpdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make quickUpdate Integer variable not String and it is going to work

Answer (score 0):

It's because `quickUpdate` is a `String`.

Use this instead: `quickUpdate = Integer.parseInt(mAthlete_etCompScore.getText().toString());`.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `quickUpdate` as `int` and change to:

```
quickUpdate = Integer.parseInt(mAthlete_etCompScore.getText().toString());
quickUpdate = quickUpdate + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to string before doing any mathematical manipulation.

```
btnQuickUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { //ref 1


        mAthlete_etCompScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvAttent);
        //get your text into a string variable
        String str_quickUpdate = 
        String.valueOf(mAthlete_etCompScore.getText().toString());

        //Convert the string to integer value
        int quickUpdate = Integer.parseInt(str_quickUpdate.trim());
        //Your increment here
        quickUpdate = quickUpdate + 1;


        Book book = new Book();

        book.setAuthor(quickUpdate);
```